# Weird characters are outputted using UTF-8

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, utf-8, non-ascii-characters

I am using code igniter framework and added the  header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");  in server side as well as the < meta charset="UTF-8">,
< meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> in client side code.
When I type a french character with accent as input it keeps saving as weird characters like copyright symbol and weird A's. Im using javascript to encode the input and it encodes correctly into & #224; etc. but when I try decoding it with innerHTML it doesnt output the correct characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers I found the issue, it was because I was not passing 'UTF-8' as a parameter while calling htmlentities() in php code. there was no need for me to try to encode it in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function to convert UTF-8 to HTML entities.

Also make sure you've [set your HTML document to UTF-8](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-charset) using `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.

Comment: i dont think htmlspecialchars() will do french conversions. also i need to use a javascript equivalence of htmlentities() as I cant embed php in a javascript function.

Comment: @user2839200 It will actually... Just try it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your text editor is set to utf-8. I had the same issue using Nusphere, it was automatticaly using another charset (like Windows-....)  after deleting file and created another with UTF-8 settings, it worked ok.

Comment: i checked encoding of the php file in notepad++ and it says UTF-8 without BOM